# Override find_for_authentication method for two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have two model for devise authentification: User and Client.

I need to override this method (lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb) with different conditions for each model

```
def find_for_authentication(tainted_conditions)
find_first_by_auth_conditions(tainted_conditions, active: true)
end
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_for_authentication(tainted_conditions)
    client = super
    find_first_by_auth_conditions(tainted_conditions, active: true)
    client
  end
end
```

Try this if it helps

Comment: Method doesn't override if I put it in Client Model.

Comment: @gmrash- and what happens when you put it in authenticatable model as a class method.

Comment: Nothing, Client logging in using parametres from lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb

Comment: @gmrash - so its allowing you to override the method or not by defining it in authenticatable model as class method `self.find_for_authentication(tainted_conditions)`